# How can I convert a list of float values to a string of hex?

Tags: automation, scripting, batch-processing, floating-point-conversion

To start off, I'm not a programmer or script writer. I'm modding a 3d model file of a game and it involves using a hex editor to input values into the float32 box in a hex editor like HxD.

So i'm basically putting in values for stuff like vertex coordinates, UV coordinates, etc.
HxD automatically converts the values i put in the float32 box to hex. (All tested, works in-game). However this a long tedious process because i have to put the values in one by one by one.

My question is, is there a script or program where i can just paste a list of values, like:

```
0.298584
0.423096
0.308350
0.417480
0.268066
0.392578
0.321045
0.464844
0.309814
0.464844
0.308350
0.511963
0.298584
0.506348
0.268066
0.536865
0.284668
0.498291
0.260010
0.523193
```

Then the script will automatically convert the list of values as float32 into hex, like:

```
01 E0 98 3E 0A A0 D8 3E 0D E0 9D 3E F0 BF D5 3E F2 3F 89 3E FC FF C8 3E 03 60 A4 3E 08 00 EE 3E F1 9F 9E 3E 08 00 EE 3E 0D E0 9D 3E 02 10 03 3F 01 E0 98 3E 06 A0 01 3F F2 3F 89 3E FC 6F 09 3F 01 C0 91 3E FF 1F FF 3E 08 20 85 3E FA EF 05 3F
```

or

```
01E0983E0AA0D83E0DE09D3EF0BFD53EF23F893EFCFFC83E0360A43E0800EE3EF19F9E3E0800EE3E0DE09D3E0210033F01E0983E06A0013FF23F893EFC6F093F01C0913EFF1FFF3E0820853EFAEF053F
```

It would help me make this process less time consuming.

I've been searching other stackoverflow questions, but most of them seem to focus on converting a single float to hex rather than a list of floats. That plus i have limited scripting, programming knowledge.

Comment: `perl -pae '$_ = uc unpack "H*", pack "f*", @F' < infile`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!
It didn't work at first, it gave me the error "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1."
But I just swapped all the ' with " and the " with ' and then it worked perfectly!